# Python | Почему тангенс π/2 = 1.633123935319537e+16?

Tags: python, математика

Почему тангенс π/2 = 1.633123935319537e+16?

Код:

```
import math
print(math.tan(math.pi /  2))
```

Результат:
1.633123935319537e+16

Comment: Просто интересно - а что вы ожидали? :)

Comment: @Harry, ну я бы ожидал встроенный во float Infinity

Comment: @EzikBro, это можно было бы сделать, если бы функция работала бы с градусами, тогда вы проверяли бы просто на 90 + 180*n и выдавали бы соответствующее значение, а так у вас лишь приближенное значение получается и не понятно - а имелось в виду именно pi / 2 или рядом

Comment: @EzikBro а от math.pi вы что ожидаете? А что там на самом деле?

Comment: @Эникейщик От math.pi я не ожидаю даже того, что я помню наизусть. Но все-таки поведение немного неожиданное, когда не вдумываешься в него.

Comment: @EzikBro Если хотите работать с точными числами, то надо использовать более продвинутые библиотеки. Обычный питоновский `float` не для такого, к сожалению.

Comment: @EzikBro Т.е. вы и от `math.pi` ожидаете абсолютную точность?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что `pi` - это 180 градусов, `pi / 2` - это 90 градусов, а тангенс стремится к бесконечности при стремлении к 90 градусам

кроме того тангенс - это синус делить на косинус, а точность `float` значений все таки не абсолютная, поэтому деление на `0` может и не происходить, поэтому могут получаться какие-то конечные значения

ну и в третьих синус, косинус, тангенс и т.д. можно вычислять (а возможно так и вычисляются) как ряд тейлора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а значит учитывая точность float будет лишь приближенное значение и в вашем случае это 1.633123935319537e+16

кстати из-за алгоритма вычисления тригонометрических функций и `cos(math.pi / 2)` равен не `0`, а `6.123233995736766e-17`

**P.S.**

попробовал подсчитать `cos(pi / 2)` через ряд Тейлора:

```
import math

value = math.pi / 2

res = 0
for i in range(50):
    res += (-1)**i * (value**(2*i + 1) / math.factorial(2 * i))

print(res)
```

Вместо `0` получил `1.2246167519384833e-16` как и ожидалось

Вот график значений `lg(|cos(x)|)` (для удобства взял логарифмическую шкалу, чтобы лучше показать) от кол-ва шагов вычисления - видно, что после 10 шага точность не меняется (достигли предела точности чисел с плавающей запятой):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну и в-четвертых, math.pi совсем не равно π. И не может быть равно по определению.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать более точные библиотеки, например:

```
from sympy import pi, tan

print(tan(pi / 2))
```

Вывод:

```
zoo (complex infinity)
```